# How to get my .net dll to be referenced in vba/com?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

i have a .net dll which is written in c sharp, which uses linq to read data and return it to another calling vba app. i didn't plan for this so the initial project was written for it to be accessible by another .net app. so now i just found out that there's a lot of stuff about .net com interoperability and what not.

so i've learned that i need to user interface to make it work, and i need to regasm the dll to create a type library file which i can reference directly from the vba/vb6 app.

as of now i'm getting the problem of when i do this Dim obj As DtasApiTool.Program, it's fine but on the next line set obj = new DtasApiTool.Program will cause an error about New operator not being used properly. when i tested [another .net dll from codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx) it works fine.

so my question is, what am i doing wrong here?

1. am i using too many references, as in
   the using system.xxx?
2. or is it due
       to some files that i have in the
       projects, i.e. app.config 
   file, etc.
3. and how do i get the guid?

as i have very limited knowledge or experience in all of this ,i'm basing what is right or wrong from the example code in code project :( so feel free to comment on anything.

this is the code that i'm using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
//using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace DtasApiTool
{
    [Guid("D6F88E95-8A27-4ae6-B6DE-0542A0FC7059")]
    [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
    public interface _Program
    {
    [DispId(1)]
    string Get_All_Locales();

    [DispId(2)]
    string Get_All_Levels(string locale);

    [DispId(3)]
    string Get_Subjects_ByLocaleLevelId(string locale, int levelId);

    [DispId(4)]
    string Get_Topic_ByLevelIdLocaleSubjectId(int levelId, string locale, int subjectId);

    [DispId(5)]
    string Get_Subtopic_ByLevelIdLocaleSubjectIdTopicId(int levelId, string locale, int subjectId, int topicId);

    [DispId(6)]
    string Get_Skill_ByLevelIdLocaleSubjectIdTopicIdSubtopicId(int levelId, string locale, int subjectId, int topicId, int subtopicId);

    [DispId(7)]
    string Get_All_Subjects(string locale);

}

[Guid("09FE32AD-4BF8-495f-AB4D-6C61BD463EA4")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("DtasApiTool.Program")]
public class Program : _Program
{
...}
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the "Register for COM interop" flag in the project properties?

Comment: yup, that's the first thing that i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm - I'm using C# DLLs all the time with COM and never had problems. I'm not even using the interface-approach you have there. This is, for example, an anonymized part of a DLL I'm using in Microsoft Dynamics NAV via COM:

```
using ...;

namespace SomeCOMTool
{
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [ProgId("MyCOMTool")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("your-guid-here without curly brackets!")]
    public class MyCOMTool
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Empty constructor used by Navision to create a new instance of the control.
        /// </summary>
        public MyCOMTool()
        {
        }

        [DispId(101)]
        public bool DoSomething(string input, ref string output)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Of course "COM visible" is set in the assembly options and there's also a GUID in the respective field.

Comment: @Thorsten, i've narrow down my problem to the fact that the constructor that i use has a parameter value which seems to be causing the problem. so am i not allowed to use any constructor with parameters for this situation?

Comment: When using COM with Navision, the constructor must be parameterless, but I can't tell you if that's always a requirement - for that I do not know enough about COM interop. If in doubt, remove the parameter and instead provide an Init-method that takes the parameter and does the initialization you'd have done in the constructor.

Comment: Also, in your description "set obj = ..." you don't write anything about the parameter - maybe that's the problem? Calling the constructor without parameter?

Comment: @Thorsten, it seems that i'm having problem with my functions that has parameters in them. when i try to call them in vb6 via function_name(parameter) i get an error run-time error 450 wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Comment: I'm not a VB6 expert, but maybe it might help to add "Option Explicit" at the beginning of the module to make sure all variables are actually declared. Otherwise I'd suggest you open a new question and ask explicitly for your 450 error.

Comment: Thorsten's suspicion is right. From MSDN "Types must have a public default constructor, which is the only constructor that can be invoked through COM."

Comment: @Thorsten, @Andreas, i guess what i'm trying to do is to pass arguments to the methods in .net dll but is unable to do so. can you guys tell me what i'm doing wrong? thanks.

Comment: Hi, as I suggested, open a new question asking specifically about the problem you have passing parameters. You will reach a broader audience. I do not know enough about VBA/VB6/COM interop to help you on that.